# different result from query between postgresql and ssrs

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services

I am really having an issue with my postgre query. I am producing a report to compare two different DB systems and just found out that some data are missing on the postgre DB when I query the DB. I checked the DB and the data is there, but not showing up . What is happening. I used this query below in SSRS and postgresql. it is producing different results.I have also deledeted the file.rdl.data on my project file as well.

```
`SELECT  "public".aircraft.aircraft_id, "public".aircraft.register_number, to_char("public".flight.flight_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as flight_date , to_char("public".flight.health_start_date, 'hh24:mi') as health_start_date, to_char("public".flight.health_end_date, 'HH24:MI') as health_end_date,  "public".flight.maintenance_flight_time
FROM  "public".flight  

INNER JOIN   "public".aircraft
ON
"public".flight.aircraft_id = "public".aircraft.id
WHERE "public".flight.maintenance_flight_time > 0
ORDER BY flight_date`
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're joining on the right columns? Without a specific sample of data I'm afraid there's not much we can do to tell you why the query isn't working.

Comment: I have deleted the filename.rdl.data and still no solution

Comment: You are joining on `public.flight.aircraft_id = public.aircraft.id`, but in `SELECT` you write `public.aircraft.aircraft_id`. Is there a typo here?

Comment: I will check again now

Comment: The aircraft id and id are the common values in both DB. The name of the first table is flight and has aircraft_id and the name of the second table is aircraft and has id. I refresh this morning and create another report, it works normal and then after it started the problem again. something is not right somewhere. I just do not want to install again the SSRS DT

Comment: You still haven't provided enough context for anyone to be able to help you. Reinstalling SSDT won't help. It doesn't even sound like problem with SSRS. What are the two DBs? Are they both Prostgre? If not, what is the other SQL query? What tool are you writing the SQL in? When you run the queries in that tool do you get the same results? What steps did you take to confirm that aircraft.aircraft_id is not the common value?

Comment: It is the same DB and I have confirmed that public.flight.aircraft_id = public.aircraft.id are common id. i know it is confusing about the common value, but that is it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It is resolved now. I did not do anything than to move the project folder to another location. It is strange. I believe alse deleting filename.rdl.data in project folder helped as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved now. I did not do anything than to move the project folder to another location. It is strange. I believe alse deleting filename.rdl.data in project folder helped as well –